# Force shutdown without checking open process Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, kill-process, system-shutdown

Is there any way to force shutdown without checking or waiting running procceses to terminate.
More specifically, i want something like unpluging the socket. Setting the value of WaitTimeToKillApp in registry as zero doesn't do the job, the window that says:"If you force shutdown you will lose your unsaved job" keeps popping up.
Can anyone explain what checks the windows does explicitly, in order to shutdown so i can cancel them.

**EDIT:**
Make the system kill itself ignoring ANY procceses (not only procecses EVERYTHING)

Comment: guessing, but it probably broadcasts an "is it ok to shutdown?" message to all processes. if any reply 'no', you get that warning.

Comment: Make the system kill itself ignoring ANY procceses (not only procecses EVERYTHING).

Answer (score 0):

The [`shutdown`](http://ss64.com/nt/shutdown.html) command might work for you.

```
/t:xxx         : Time until system shutdown in seconds. 
                    The valid range is xxx=0-600 seconds. [default=30]    
   /f             : Force running applications to close.
```

example command

```
shutdown /t:0 /f
```

Comment: I want something like flushing the memory of RAM. Like force killing the operating system, not waiting to kill each process one by one, so every runnning process can terminate. 
I don't want to have to wait for all the updates, confirmations and other many unwanted things windows do. 
Is there something similar to sudo shutdown in unix?